# How to remove shipping from Cart (Magento 2.4)

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, magento2.4.2

I am trying to remove the Shipping & Coupon container from the `/checkout/cart` page. I tried to copy the XML file into `layout/override/base` and edit it, but then I get blank page on `/cart`.

A simpler way would be by hiding it via CSS, but I am trying to do it programatically and proper way.

Currently I have following container as shown in the image, which I want to disable from the cart page.

[image]

And the code to show this container exist in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` , I also tried to comment out the block inside this file, but then everything gets messed up i.e. checkout process too.

**UPDATE**

I was able to do it by following [this](https://www.magemonkeys.com/magento-2-how-to-remove-estimate-shipping-costs-and-tax-block-form-cart-page/) however, I had to edit the actual XML file, if I place the code in `override/base/XML` then it doesn't work, and I get a blank page. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below:

```
<referenceBlock name=""checkout.cart.shipping"">
    <arguments>
        <argument name=""jsLayout"" xsi:type=""array"">
            <item name=""components"" xsi:type=""array"">
                <item name=""block-summary"" xsi:type=""array"">

                    <!-- My custom part: -->
                    <item name=""config"" xsi:type=""array"">
                        <item name=""componentDisabled"" xsi:type=""boolean"">true</item>
                    </item>

                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

To remove the heading as well, override the template checkout/cart/shipping.phtml and comment/remove the following:

```
<div class=""title"" data-role=""title"">
    <strong id=""block-shipping-heading"" role=""heading"" aria-level=""2"">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getQuote()->isVirtual() ? __('Estimate Tax') : __('Estimate Shipping and Tax') ?>
    </strong>
</div>
```

Documents for your reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable-a-component

Answer (score 0):

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/themename/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="cart.discount" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

[Create a new storefront theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)